# Can you run an .exe file through tkinter-Python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I was wondering if anyone can help me with a stupid problem, i am trying to see if an exe file can be opened in a specific part of the screen and stay there. I cant figure out how to make it open in a specific part of the screen or how to make it lock there. Basically i want it to open in the GUI and stay in its designated spot. I have attached my tkinter interface. Does anyone have any clue how to do this?

```
import tkinter as tk

HEIGHT = 720
WIDTH = 1280
FRAMECOLOR = '#80c1ff'
BUTTONFILLCOLOR = 'gray'

def start():
    os.startfile(r'INSERT EXE FILE')

def stop():
    print("Stopped")

def restart():
    print("Restart")

def serverini():
    print("Opened")

def kick():
    print("Kicked Player")

def autorestart():
    print("Auto Restart True")

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=HEIGHT, width=WIDTH)
canvas.pack()

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg=FRAMECOLOR, bd=5)
frame.place(relx=0.35, rely=0.8, relwidth=0.5, relheight=0.1, anchor='n')

lower_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg=FRAMECOLOR, bd=10)
lower_frame.place(relx=0.35, rely=0.1, relwidth=0.5, relheight=0.67, anchor='n')

button_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg=FRAMECOLOR, bd=10)
button_frame.place(relx=0.75, rely=0.1, relwidth = 0.25, relheight=0.8, anchor='n')

entry = tk.Entry(frame, font=40)
entry.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

button1 = tk.Button(button_frame, text="Start", font=40, command=start)
button1.place(relx=0.001, rely=0, relwidth=1, relheight=0.1)

button2 = tk.Button(button_frame, text="Stop", font=40, command=stop)
button2.place(relx=0.001, rely=0.11, relwidth=1, relheight=0.1)

button3 = tk.Button(button_frame, text="Restart", font=40, command=restart)
button3.place(relx=0.001, rely=0.22, relwidth=1, relheight=0.1)

button4 = tk.Button(button_frame, text="Server ini File", font=40, command=serverini)
button4.place(relx=0.001, rely=0.33, relwidth=1, relheight=0.1)

button5 = tk.Button(button_frame, text="Auto Restart", font=40, command=autorestart)
button5.place(relx=0.001, rely=0.33, relwidth=1, relheight=0.1)

button6 = tk.Button(button_frame, text="Kick", font=40, command=kick)
button6.place(relx=0.001, rely=0.44, relwidth=1, relheight=0.1)

label = tk.Label(lower_frame)
label.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Thanks - Connor

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow. You aren't supposed to post your whole code here but rather a [mre]

Comment: Sadly not possible. Tkinter cannot control the position of the window of other applications. It is up to the window manager (which is OS/distribution specific) to decide where windows are placed and allow the user to interact with them. If this is a command line program, you can re-direct the text output to tkinter